# XAML how to style menuitems whitin a specific menu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a menu that has a style tag (with as value StaticResource ...)

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource TopToolBar}">
```

In my app.xaml I have the following code

```
<Style TargetType="Menu" x:Key="TopToolBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomFontBold}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainColor_1}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
</Style>
```

How do I style the menu items for this specific menu
These styles must only apply to the menu items that belong to this menu.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomFontBold}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AlternativeColor_2}"/>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for that one Menu, you could define it inside the Menu's scope, like this:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource TopToolBar}">
  <Menu.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomFontBold}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource AlternativeColor_2}"/>
    </style>
  </Menu.Resources>
 </Menu>
```